# Delphi - Excel: Define a non-contiguous range

Tags: delphi, excel-2010

What I have is a sheet with data and I want to define a non-contiguous range that can be used to, as an example, create a chart.

As long as the range is rectangular it's pretty easy defining the range.

```
range := ASheet.Range['A1', 'B10'];
```

This creates a rectangular range with the top left corner at `A1` and bottom right corner in `B10`. The problem is when the data isn't defined so that it can be selected with a single rectangle.

As an example we have this data:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| Time  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| 01:20 |    5 |    1 |  101 |   51 |
| 01:21 |    6 |    1 |  101 |   51 |
| 01:22 |    5 |    0 |  101 |   51 |
| 01:23 |    5 |    0 |  101 |   51 |
| 01:24 |    5 |    0 |  101 |   55 |
| 01:25 |    5 |    1 |  101 |   55 |
| 01:26 |    6 |    1 |  101 |   15 |
| 01:27 |    7 |    2 |  101 |   15 |
| 01:28 |    7 |    2 |  101 |   15 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

If I for example wish to create a chart for *Time, Col1 and Col2* then the range is simply `ASheet.Range['A1', 'C10']`. If I want to create the chart for *Time, Col1, Col3 and Col4* it's not possible to create a range this way (since Col2 shouldn't be included).

In VBA it's possible to create the desired range by simply `.Range("A1:B10,D1:E10")`. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way of defining a range in Delphi (Excel2010), in fact it seems to only support range with the format `.Range[topLeft, bottomRight]`.

**My question is:** How do I define a non-contiguous range in Delphi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After hours and hours of googling I stumbled upon the key part: [`Application.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621%28v=office.14%29.aspx), when reading through the [documentation for Range object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for the nth time.

The solution is to use the Excel object method `Union` to make a union of two contiguous  ranges in order to define a new range, which can be non-contiguous.

Example:

```
ExcelApp := TExcelApplication.Create(..);
...
Range1 := Sheet.Range['A1', 'B10'];
Range2 := Sheet.Range['D1', 'E10'];

Range  := ExcelApp.Union(Range1, Range2);
```

Comment: Links to other Excel versions of the same function: [Excel 2013 Application.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621(v=office.15).aspx); [Excel 2010 Application.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621(v=office.14).aspx); [Excel 2007 Application.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178176(v=office.12).aspx); [Excel 2003 Application.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx);